# Best approach to keep user session alive in Mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, cordova, authentication, hybrid-mobile-app

We have developed a mobile application (Android & iOS) which has custom login with limited session expiry time (3 days). The session will expire after 3 days and we are showing Login page to re-login.

But we don't want to show login page to the user. What are the best approach to do that.

**Approach 1:**

In the server side, do not set the expiry date to the generated session. So that session will not expire until user logged out.

**Approach 2:**

In UI, save the username & password in permanent storage like sqlite & etc. When the session expired (after 3 days in my case), UI has to send **hidden** login call to get new session id. In this case we will not redirect to login page.

How other mobile apps keep the session Id's alive till user logout.

Please suggest me any other best approach apart from above 2 approaches.

Comment: But data server send you after login?

Comment: does it contains any token?

Comment: In the login call response, server will send response along with session id. We are sending that session id in every API call. In each call, server is validating that session id. If that session is expired, then server is sending "Token expired" message. So then we are redirecting to login page.

Server is not sending session in any other API call except login API call.

Comment: I think there're only that 2 approach, rather prolong the session than saving the username and password on the app

Comment: If you want to store the username and password on iOS, use the keychain.

Comment: Storing credentials on the phone is not a good approach for security.
http://mobilesecurityares.blogspot.in/2014/12/why-passwords-should-not-be-stored-on.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following approach to solve your issue, I have faced same issue and used same approach :

Server should send a extra RefreshToken with your sessionId.
Or server should provide a different API to refresh your sessionId with that refreshToken.

So suppose you get “invalid token” error, then you need to follow following steps :

- call RefreshToken API using last saved RefreshToken.
- Server should refresh that sessionID & reset expiryTime to 3 days and reply you with new SessionID.
- Server should create new RefreshToken at their end only whenever you logOut/login again And when 3 days expires(means user haven’t used app for 3 days so he should be logged out).
- So you should be logout only when that RefreshToken expires.
- you will get new sessionID and then use that for further requests & for that request on which you got that error.

Comment: On calling of RefreshToken API call, will the server create new sessionID? or same session id with new expiry date?

Comment: Why this refreshToken approach is better? Is there any extra advantage?

Comment: you can do both.. depends on your security concerns.

Comment: yes because saving userName password is not a good approach for security.

Comment: In the same way, keeping the long expiry date to sessionID is also not a better approach for security right?

Comment: Right.. but when you get invalidToken error, the request being called between that time of Refrestoken request.. you need to wait to get new token.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131128/discussion-between-sivakumar-and-nehak).

Comment: What is the advantage of sending refreshToken in RefreshToken API call?
May be sessionID is associated with refreshToken right ? If we wont send refreshToken then server dont know which sessionId to refresh.

Comment: How is this approach better than allowing long sessions? Can't we assume that on mobile if an attacker gained access to the sessionId then they probably also were able to access the refreshToken?